# Multer : Setting different destinations in the destination Property

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, multer

I have a case where I need to store images in different directories . So I have set the multer as.

```
    app.use(multer({
  dest: path.join(__dirname, '`public/assets/img/profile`'),
  rename: function (fieldname, filename, req, res) {
    if(req.session.user) return req.session.user.id;
    else if(req.session.doctor) return req.session.doctor.id;
  }
}));
```

However I need more destinations to store images.

```
public/assets/img/picture1
```

I have seen similar questions but I could not understand any of them.
Any help would be greatfull.

Comment: How do you determine which directory you store an image in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is from quite old version of multer. I strongly recommend you to use latest version (due to security reasons).

If you are sure that you need old version then just add to your multer options:

```
app.use(multer({
  //...
  changeDest: function(dest, req, res) {
    return dest + '/user1'; 
  }
  //...
}));
```

More details you will get in documentation (link to old version) [link](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/blob/e806a01a23592ef79eb890cfcb33258bd4207be5/README.md)

Newest version of multer works a little different. This would be to big offtopic to write in detail how to use new version of multer. You easily will find in stackoverflow answer or from actual version of documentation [link](https://github.com/expressjs/multer)

I only write how to change destination directory (example from docs):

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, '/tmp/my-uploads')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
  }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage })

app.post('/profile', upload.single('picture'), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.file is the `picture` file
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
})
```

Comment: Thanks I will try to implement it and see.

Comment: can you please tell me how does multer handles callback I was really frustrated with filter in multer i was not able to achieve with this I tried some other  way that's not good I felt so

Comment: @santhosh maybe you could open new issue (you can add link to that issue in this comment, then I will try to help you). This is because I have some questions. And this is less readable in comments. In new topic you can write, what version on multer you use (old or new api), write some code, which makes you troubles. What you want to achieve, what you get.